# Win32Exception: The network path was not found (localhost error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

OK people say this is ConnectionString issue but my code runs fine on server but give me this error on localhost: http://pastebin.com/9Y8reGE7

Any insights why it would do this for localhost, I didn't change the project at all then when I came back to it after some motnhs of not working on it... It looks like I can't connect to my sql server? If Anybody had the same issue please help with solution

*16.9.2016*

I'm still getting this error, only on localhost - my site works fine on server any suggestions please?!

I can't make edits because I get this exception everytime i run my site on localhost!

Comment: try this blog https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/

Comment: it turns out that it was some kind of server-side error, our host provider managed to get rid of this error after some time...